# How to disable specific date materialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is a javascript made by materialize, and I am trying to disable specific dates. But I tried a lot of code here but could not get any result from this.

```
<script>

var dateToday = new Date();
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  selectMonths: true,
  selectYears: 40,
  format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
  min: dateToday,
  max: new Date(2030, 11, 31),
  closeOnSelect: true,
    onOpen: function () {
      this.clear();
    },
    onSet: function () {
      var x,y,year,date,month;
      x = $('.datepicker1').pickadate().val().toString();
      y = x.split(/[ ,]+/);
      date = y[0];
      month = y[1];
      year = y[2];
      console.log(y[0]+" "+ y[1]+ " "+ y[2]);
      if(date && month && year){
        this.close();
      }
    }
});

$("#mcDateFrom").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $("#mcDateFrom").first().pickadate("picker").open();
});
$("#mcDateTo").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $("#mcDateTo").first().pickadate("picker").open();
});

</script>
```

I am also trying the below code also.

```
 var array = ["2018-06-28","2013-03-15","2013-03-16"]

$('.datepicker').pickadate({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.pickadate.formatDate('yyyy-mm-dd', date);
        return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }
});
```

But no result after trying a lot of things as well as this code. I need help. Thanks in advance.